# How to set web proxy info for a web service call in NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, macos, web-services, cocoa

I am trying to call a web service from objectiove-c.

My code is

```
    -(BOOL)requestWebServiceURL:(NSURL *)URL withPostData:(NSString*)postData
    {
        NSLog(@"%d",[NSThread currentThread].isMainThread ? 1:0);
        NSLog(@"*****requesting WebService URL***for class name ==** %@  ",self.callingClass);
        NSLog(@"POstDataRecieved %@",postData);
        NSData *dataToPost = [postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *dataToPostLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)[dataToPost length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *r = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]autorelease];
        [r setURL:URL];
        [r setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [r setValue:dataToPostLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [r setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [r setHTTPBody:dataToPost];
        [r setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
        NSLog(@"\n\nSENDING data");
        self.receivedData = [[[NSMutableData alloc] init]autorelease];
        NSURLConnection *URLConnection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:r delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
        NSLog(@"____>>>>  %@",URLConnection);
        NSLog(@"**____  %d",[NSThread currentThread].isMainThread ? 1:0);
        return TRUE;
    }
```

How can i set the proxy server information i.e (server address,port,username and password) for this web service call.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NSURL classes wont have those methods. You need to use CFURL.

You can also use the delegate method didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:

```c
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username"
                                                                    password:@"password"
                                                                 persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you plz provide a sample or some pointers where i can find these samples